# OAuth 2 OIDC Grant type for 1st-party native mobile applications

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4, access-token, openid-connect, refresh-token

Which grant type do 1st-party native applications on phone use? Since they own the native apps and the API, they never show an Authorization screen or in-app browser tabs when user wants to sign-in. 
For example Facebook, Google, Instagram, LinkedIn etc, what Grant type are they using to obtain both Access and Refresh tokens as users are not redirected to the in app brower tabs while logging in.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely ResourceOwnerPassword but I'd imagine they are doing lots of custom stuff too to support their own flavours of 2FA etc.

In this case you do not need a refresh token as you have captured their credentials directly in the app and thus can replay the token endpoint request whenever you like.

Comment: You mean that when we provide username and password, they are storing it at client and then uses them again and again to obtain access tokens?

Comment: Well thanks a lot for your responses but in the meantime, i did a lot of R&D and what i guess is that; they use ResourceOwnerPassword Grant type with offline access scope (that gives them refresh token as well). And they store both access token and refresh token as well for subsequent requests.

Comment: All I'm saying is that the refresh token is redundant if you already know the user's password and ROP grant type is available. It's a hint as to why ROP is generally considered to be bad - check out https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/Why-the-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-Grant-Type-is-not-Authentication-nor-Suitable-for-Modern-Applications